# Why does writeObject throw java.io.NotSerializableException and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, exception, serialization, notserializableexception

I have this exception and I don't understand why it would be thrown or, how I  should handle it.

```
try {
    os.writeObject(element);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where `element` is a `TransformGroup` containing some other `TransformGroups` an instance of the class Atom:

```
public class Atom extends Group implements Serializable{
    float pozX,pozY;
    Group group= new Group();   
    Color3f blue = new Color3f(new Color(255));
    Color3f black = new Color3f(new Color(0));
    Sphere AtSph=new Sphere();

    public Atom(final float WEIGHT, final int BOUNDS,final float radius,Color3f color)
    {
        AppSetting ap= new AppSetting(color, black);
        AtSph=new Sphere(radius,1,100,ap);
    }
}
```

The full error log:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at cls.MolecularBuilder.addAtom(MolecularBuilder.java:511)
    at cls.MolecularBuilder$Console.HidrogenItemActionPerformed(MolecularBuilder.java:897)
    at cls.MolecularBuilder$Console$2.actionPerformed(MolecularBuilder.java:746)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`AppSetting` (in Atom class) is just a custom class that extends Appearance.

Comment: Looks like `javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup` itself does not implement Serializable

Comment: Why does `Atom` both extend `Group` and have a `Group` member?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

The fields of your object have in turn their fields, some of which do not implement `Serializable`. In your case the offending class is `TransformGroup`. How to solve it?

- if the class is yours, make it `Serializable`
- if the class is 3rd party, but you don't need it in the serialized form, mark the field as `transient`
- if you need its data and it's third party, consider other means of serialization, like JSON, XML, BSON, [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html), etc. where you can get 3rd party objects serialized without modifying their definitions.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, it will be quite a hard thing to do, since my objects only exist as part of the TransformGroup, and there are not any variables that store them. My app is a 3d molecule builder, and all my atoms and bounds are just added to the TransformGroup as instances- e.g (new Atom()). The problem is not only that I need them written to a file, but that the user may want to remove or edit current objects. I think I will try some XML-based serialization, but I am quite new to the concept and it's a bit hard for me yet.
Thank you

Comment: To add to this excellent answer: if you need its data and it's third party, you may want to wrap the third party class into your own class, which implements `Serializable` and uses `readObject()` and `writeObject()` to manually serialize the data of the third party class. In some cases this might be a reasonable approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12963580/1208581

Answer (score 89):

`java.io.NotSerializableException` can occur when you serialize an **inner class instance** because:

> serializing such an inner class instance will result in serialization
> of its associated outer class instance as well
>
> **Serialization of inner classes** (i.e., nested classes that are not
> static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is
> **strongly discouraged**

Ref: [The Serializable Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4539)

Comment: This was the case for me. It was happening when I took a short cut on a unit test. Hope this answer saves someone else some time.

Comment: I had a field     private final Set<ClaimsNode> outgoing = new TreeSet<ClaimsNode>(new Comparator<ClaimsNode>() {
        public int compare(ClaimsNode o1, ClaimsNode o2) {
            return o1.getNativeIndex() - o2.getNativeIndex();
        }
    });

Comment: Amazing, Literally I was into this for past 1 hour. I started doubting that even primitive ints are not serializable and then it occurred to me, that perhaps something is really wrong here.

Answer (score 10):

Make the class serializable by implementing the interface `java.io.Serializable`.

- `java.io.Serializable` - Marker Interface which does not have any methods in it.
- Purpose of Marker Interface - to tell the `ObjectOutputStream` that this object is a serializable object.

Comment: You can read question, its already implementing Serializable.  Still 12+ amaze me.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above if the class is a 3rd party class you need to convert it to a JSON/XML/BSON object as the 3rd party class object cannot be serialized.

I was working on my project and had the same issue and i used gson library to convert my class object to a JSON String. Afterwhich i used this String in that object and passed it through ObjectOutputStream object.
And over the client side i used the same to revert the JSON String back to the 3rd party class object.

You can download the jar from over here : https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/source-code!

Here's how i did it :

```
// Method that returns String through a Object as a parameter i.e to be converted

 public static String  generateJSONStringFromObject(ThirdPartyClass object) throws JsonProcessingException{
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            
                return jsonString;
        }

// Method that returns Object through a String as a parameter 

 public static ThirdPartyClass generateObjectFromJSONString(String jsonString){
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ThirdPartyClass thirdPartyClassObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ThirdPartyClass.class);
            return thirdPartyClassObject;
        }
```