# An error: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class define as follow

```
public class EvaluationResult implements java.io.Serializable {
    public String ClassName;
    public boolean FeedbackDirected;
    public double HV;
    public double Spread;
    public double PercentageOfCorrectness;
    public double TimeElapsed;
    public ArrayList<double[]> ParetoFront;


}
```

Doing this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         EvaluationResult ae=new EvaluationResult();
         FileOutputStream fileOut =new FileOutputStream("result.txt");
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
         out.writeObject(fileOut);
         out.close();
         fileOut.close();
     }
```

gives me `java.io.NotSerializableException` what is the problem?

Comment: If you want to dump an object as a sequence of bytes, the class will have to implement the Serializable marker interface.

Comment: Need stacktrace of the exception. Otherwise it is not possible to pin point the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895867/java-io-notserializableexception

Comment: No problem now, just that I need to out.writeObject(ae);, thanks

Answer (score 3):

you need to implement Serializable marker interface

```
 public class EvaluationResult implements Serializable { .... }
```

You should be writing the object (and not the file stream) :

```
 out.writeObject(ae);
```

Answer (score 3):

You must implement `Serializable` in the class definition:

```
public class EvaluationResult implements Serializable {
    public String ClassName;
    public boolean FeedbackDirected;
    public double HV;
    public double Spread;
    public double PercentageOfCorrectness;
    public double TimeElapsed;
    public ArrayList<double[]> ParetoFront;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the Serializable interface ... this implies implementing the following:

Classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods with these exact signatures:

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
 private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

This [tutorial may be of use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)