# NotSerializableException when sending an Object

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, notserializableexception

I want to create an instance , put it on a container and send it.

```
TransferContainer container = null;
    ...
  Class aClass = container.getByteCode();
    o = aClass.newInstance();
    ....// Some code
    ...
    container.setInstance(o);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(_s.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(container);
```

I get  this error

> java.io.NotSerializableException
>   If I don't add the the instance o in the container I can send it without any problem.

Comment: Read more about the [java.io.NotSerializableException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895867/java-io-notserializableexception) First point make it Serializable

Comment: right, this is the correct error in this case, what is your question?

Comment: for better help sooner please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates de issue.

Comment: Class aClass = container.getByteCode();

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about failing to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this exception is that aClass or some instance field of aClass doesn't implement Serializable.

Comment: aClass can be any given class by the user , Class aClass = container.getByteCode();

Comment: @user567 fine. But if u want to serialize it , its all instance fields must implement serializable or make them transient if they are not required otherwise this is expected error.

Comment: @user567 Then your design is wrong. You can only allow classes that are Serializable.

Comment: If it is some kind of API you are publishing then properly document it also so that user are aware of this fact before sending any class.