# I came across the following paragraph in a java text book about serializing/deserializing objects, I find it to be wrong , am I right?

Tags: java, serialization

The text is as follows:

> If the object has a non-serializable class  somewhere up its
>   inheritance tree, the  constructor for that non-serializable class 
>   will run along with any constructors above  that (even if they're
>   serializable). Once the  constructor chaining begins, you can't stop
>   it,  which means all superclasses, beginning with  the first
>   non-serializable one, will reinitialize  their state.

My question is , if a class is non-serializable, how can any of its super classes be serializable(thats what they are implying when they say "even if they're serializable"), because if they were serializable, then the "non-serializable" subclass in question should also be serializable.

Answer (score 1):

That's true, the "(even if they're serializable)" is confusing. As you interpreted things correctly, serializability is declared by `implements Serializable` which is inherited just like any other `interface`. Therefore a `Serializable` class cannot have a non-`Serializable` subclass, at least by the definition of the interfaces. Therefore, the "with any constructors above that *(even if they're serializable)*" makes no sense.

A subclass of a `Serializable` can still prevent serialization by breaking things at runtime in multiple ways, but that doesn't make them not `Serializable` according to the technical definition of `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

> if they were serializable, then the "non-serializable" subclass in question should also be serializable.

No, that's wrong. You can write something like this:

```
class A implements Serializable {
...
}
class B extends A {
    private Object o;
    //voila! non-serializable class

}
```

You cannot add non-serializable field to class without breaking serialization. If you try to serialize/deserialize `B` objects, you'll get `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: The NotSerializableException is because class B has an instance variable Object o, which does not implement Serializable. This Exception can be overcome by changing private Object o to transient private Object o; If you do that, you no longer get the exception. You no longer get an exception because class B implicitly implements Serializable. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: `class B` can still be `Serializable` despite non-`Serializable` field `o` if it implements `readObject()` and `writeObject()` to provide handling for the non-transient fields. For example, it could be a monitor object used for `synchronized`. It's often not necessary to serialize it, so you would usually find `private Object lock;` and `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) { in.defaultReadObject(); lock = new Object(); }` and `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) { out.defaultWriteObject(); }`.

Comment: @user3760100 ofc if you remove non-serializable fields from child class you will not get an exception. But how it disprove my answer? I mean, classes inherited from serializable classes **can be** non-serializable. You *can* make them serializable using `transient` or `read/writeObject` implementation.

Comment: @Everv0id , your statement that classes inherited from serializable classes can be non-serializable is wrong. A sub class inherits all properties of its super class. If the super class has the property that it can be serialized, so does the sub class.

Comment: @user3760100 see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895867/java-io-notserializableexception). Without making non-serializable fields `transient` or implementing `readObject` and `writeObject`, you'll get `NotSerializableException` anyway.

Comment: @Everv0id just make a class A that implements Serializable, make a class B that extends A, but does not extend Serializable, create a class C that implements Serializable, create an instance variable of type B in class C and try to serialize objects of class C. They get serialized without any exceptions being thrown. This is possible, only if class B is Serializable.This proves that class B is serializable. Since class B does not implement Serializable, it's serializability can only be attributed to it extending class A which implements Serializable.

Comment: @Everv0id , the link provided by you is not official. Here is the official link provided that clearly states what I have stated previously in the first paragraph. Please have a look and let me know if I am wrong.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: @user3760100 If you try to do `readObject` or `writeObject` on object which doesn't implement `Serializable` or `Externalizable`, you'll get an exception anyway. If you doubt, see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).