# JavaFX - Saving/Loading - Shapes/Layouts

Tags: java, javafx, save, load, shapes

Is there any way to save shapes and layouts in javafx to an external file. Which can then be restored at a later time. I have tried following YouTube videos and I know how I could save/load files with "Text/Int" fields. However, I need a way of loading the last saved layout.

For example say I want to save a Polygon, I have created the following class:

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class saveFile implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Polygon fp; 
    }
```

Resource Manager Class:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream; 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ResourceManager {

public static void save(Serializable data, String fileName) throws Exception  {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
        oos.writeObject(data);
    }
}

public static Object load(String fileName) throws Exception {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
        return ois.readObject();
    }
}
}
```

Controller Class:

```
//Field
private Polygon fp = new Polygon();
@FXML
private AnchorPane container2;

//Methods
public void saveLayout(){
    saveFile data = new saveFile();
    data.fp = fp;
    try {
        ResourceManager.save(data, "savefile");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

public void loadLayout() throws IOException {
    try {
        saveFile data = (saveFile) ResourceManager.load("save");
        container2.getChildren().add(data.fp);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

I know the load method is completely wrong right now, however I thought it would be good to provide it anyways.

Edit:    e.printStackTrace(); returned:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javafx.scene.shape.Polygon
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at Model.ResourceManager.save(ResourceManager.java:14)
at Controller.NewLayoutController.saveLayout(NewLayoutController.java:191)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: and what is the exact problem? Your code should work as-is now.

Comment: The problem is when I click on the "Save" button in the program it returns the "Error" exception. It does not save it to an external file.

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: The exception prints the "Error" message I have declared in the exception.  I don't understand why it does not save it. Its been confusing me all day

Comment: Well, you should print `e`,  as well to unravel that mystery)) `System.out.println("Error", e);` but you should better use logback or something

Comment: The error message it returned has been added to my question. Can you tell where I am going wrong?   Thanks

Comment: Yep, the problem you're facing is like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13895894/5151575). I would suggest you to use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Polygon` class does not implement `Serializable` interface, that's why it cannot be serialized with standard java means.
For `Polygon` class it would be enough to save only its points in order to retrieve them later:

```
public static void save(ObservableList<Double> points, String fileName) throws Exception  {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
          oos.writeObject(new ArrayList<>(points));
    }
}
```

and then to read it back:

```
public static ObservableList<Double> load(String fileName) throws Exception {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
        List<Double> list = (List<Double>) ois.readObject();
        return FXCollections.observableList(list);
    }
}
```

And then you can construct new Polygon like:

```
ObservableList<Double> points = ResourceManager.load("save");
Polygon polygon = new Polygon()
polygon.getPoints().addAll(points);
```

Comment: And once again, for more complex serialization you should take a look on more complex tools for it (like gson). For Polygon it's rather simple, but this approach may be enough for other shapes you need to serialize.

Comment: Nice to hear that)