# NotSerializableException with an object in scala hadoop

Tags: scala, notserializableexception

```
object NearestNeighbors {

    def runNearestNeighbors(data: RDD[Array[(LabeledPoint,Int,Int)]], 
        kNN: Int, 
        sampleData: Array[(LabeledPoint,Int,Int)]): Array[(String,Array[((Int,Int),Double)])] = {

        val globalNearestNeighborsByIndex = data.mapPartitionsWithIndex(localNearestNeighbors(_,_,kNN,sampleData)).groupByKey().map(x => (x._1,x._2.toArray.sortBy(r => r._2).take(kNN))).collect()     

        globalNearestNeighborsByIndex 
    }


    private def localNearestNeighbors(partitionIndex: Long,
        iter: Iterator[Array[(LabeledPoint,Int,Int)]],
        kNN: Int,
        sampleData: Array[(LabeledPoint,Int,Int)]): Iterator[(String,((Int,Int),Double))] = { 

            var result = List[(String,((Int,Int),Double))]()
            val dataArr = iter.next
            val nLocal = dataArr.size - 1           
            val sampleDataSize = sampleData.size - 1


            val kLocalNeighbors = Array.fill[distanceIndex](sampleDataSize+1)(null)
            for {
                i1 <- 0 to sampleDataSize
            } 
            kLocalNeighbors(i1) = distanceIndex(sampleData(i1)._3.toInt, sampleData(i1)._2.toInt, DenseVector.zeros[Double](kNN) + Int.MaxValue.toDouble, DenseVector.zeros[Int](kNN))

            for (i <- 0 to nLocal) {
                val currentPoint = dataArr(i)
                val features = currentPoint._1.features
                val rowId = currentPoint._3.toInt   
                for (j <- 0 to sampleDataSize) {
                    val samplePartitionId = sampleData(j)._2
                    val sampleRowId = sampleData(j)._3
                    val sampleFeatures = sampleData(j)._1.features
                    if (!((rowId == sampleRowId) & (samplePartitionId == partitionIndex))) {
                        val distance = Math.sqrt(sum((sampleFeatures - features) :* (sampleFeatures - features)))
                        if (distance < max(kLocalNeighbors(j).distanceVector)) {
                            val indexToReplace = argmax(kLocalNeighbors(j).distanceVector)
                            kLocalNeighbors(j).distanceVector(indexToReplace) = distance
                            kLocalNeighbors(j).neighborRowId(indexToReplace) = rowId
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (m <- 0 to sampleDataSize){
                for (l <-0 to kNN-1) {

                    val key = kLocalNeighbors(m).partitionId.toString+","+kLocalNeighbors(m).sampleRowId.toString
                    val tup = (partitionIndex.toInt,kLocalNeighbors(m).neighborRowId(l))
                    result.::=(key,(tup,kLocalNeighbors(m).distanceVector(l)))
                }
            }           
        result.iterator 
    }   
}
```

I am using https://github.com/anathan90/SparkSMOTE (a library for scala) to adjust for oversampling of the minority class in the data

i have a problem with serialization and i don´t know why.

I read something about this error, but i didn't understand

The other thing is that i am running the smote script in scala hadoop and this calls this object inside other script called smote.

Here's the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: NearestNeighbors$
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: NearestNeighbors$, value: NearestNeighbors$@77542834)
        - field (class: NearestNeighbors$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class NearestNeighbors$)
        - object (class NearestNeighbors$$anonfun$1, <function2>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
```

Comment: The solution is convert make serializable the object, but objects can´t be cast to the object type because object type doesn´t exist. So at the end i convert the objects into classes and extends to serializable and implement the `writeObject` and `readObject`. Very soon i will implement a smote package to work directly in hadoop partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)
you'll see that it's an *interface* so we can check if `NearestNeighbors` satisfies it.

[`NearestNeighbors`](https://github.com/anathan90/SparkSMOTE/blob/2af48eaab7f917f4682d8772cad200f71eb46566/src/main/scala/utils/NearestNeighbors.scala) doesn't satisfy it

Comment: is there any form of fix it? I mean make it serializable

Comment: maybe, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895867/java-io-notserializableexception

Comment: they listed a few options that may be possible

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I am goint to comment the solution.

Comment: :) thanks - let everyone know if it helped by marking correct!