# How do I see where RunTimeException occurred?

Tags: android, exception, stack-trace, android-debug, google-play-console

I am seeing a lot of

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException
```

and have found [how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895867/java-io-notserializableexception). The problem is that, from stack trace reports, I am not able to see **where** this exception occurrs (this is the full report Google Play Console offers me):

[image]

How can I find this out?

Comment: do you have fragments? is one of them declared as inner class of an activity?

Comment: I use Fragments a lot, but most of them are in separate files. The one and only inner class is `class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>(); ...`.

Comment: is it static ? Are you able to reproduce the crash?

Comment: @PrimožKralj did you upload your `mapping.txt` file of your currunt app version in play store. if not upload then upload it next time you will get exact cause of error

Comment: @Blackbelt, no, it is not static. Could this be a problem? Here is [the code](https://pastebin.com/raw/08VUz3Pu). I am not able to reproduce this crash and have tried with many configurations.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari, no; I haven't uploaded the mapping.txt because the code is not minified/obfuscated.

Comment: go on that screen and try rotating the screen of your device. See if it crashes. Btw, do it `static` or move it in a different file