# MyClass NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization, vaadin10, notserializableexception

I created a class named `Components`. It has some components like `Button`, `TextArea`, `VerticalLayout`, etc. I didn't make this class serializable because I don't need to, but when I start the server (I use Tomcat), I get this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.vaadin13.Components
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
...
```

Why does this error appear when my class isn't Serializable, and how do I fix it?

Comment: 'I didn't make this class serializable because I don't need to': well. yes you *do* need to, and here is the proof. It happens *because* your class isn't `Serializable`, and the way to fix it is to *make* it implement `Serializable`. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: Is this class object refer in any Serializable class ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895867/java-io-notserializableexception

Comment: In Vaadin 8 i didn't get this error. It begins in Vaadin 10.

Comment: So soemthing changed. So make it `Serializable`. What's the mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error implement the Serializable interface and give it an id.

```
 Public class Foo implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialversionUID = 1L; // example
      //code then
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell me please why we need that variable serialversionUID?

Comment: You ll find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it