# How can I get the same reference in serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, reference

This the part where I use the serialisable interface. when I start the program it will create the same object for each list, but with different references. Is there any way to get them all as one reference?

```
private static void quitApplication(){
    System.out.println("Stopping the system...\n");
    ///store all the objects by serializing
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut2 = new FileOutputStream("FlightList.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out2 = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut2);
        out2.writeObject(Flight.getFlights());
        out2.close();
        fileOut2.close();
    }catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println("FlightList.ser ERROR");
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CityList.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(City.getCityList());
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println("CityList.ser ERROR");
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream("GrapghL.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut1);
        out1.writeObject(Test.flightGraph);
        out1.close();
        fileOut1.close();
    }catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println("GrapghL.ser ERROR");
    }
    System.out.println("Done...Thank You For using the Airlines System");
    }

private static void initializeData(){
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("CityList.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        City.setCityList((MyList<City>) in.readObject());   
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
    }catch(Exception i){
        System.out.println("CityList.ser ERROR");
    }

    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn2 = new FileInputStream("FlightList.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in2 = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn2);
        Flight.setFlights((MyList<Flight>) in2.readObject());   
        in2.close();
        fileIn2.close();

    }catch(Exception i){
        System.out.println("FlightList.ser ERROR");
    }

    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn1 = new FileInputStream("GrapghL.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in1 = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn1);
        Test.flightGraph = (DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph<City, DefaultWeightedEdge>) in1.readObject();  
        in1.close();
        fileIn1.close();

    }catch(Exception i){
        System.out.println("GrapghL.ser ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to override readObject/writeObject methods. And make a sort of EntityManager in them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963445/serialization-readobject-writeobject-overides

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting singleton values, like [`Currency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html)?

Comment: Mikhail, can the entities be in deferent classes ?

Comment: chrylis, yes, when I create a city it's added to `GraphL` when I rerun the system the `cityList` and `GraphL` have the same objects but with deferent references

Comment: You could implement a custom readResolve() method. @user2785061 The word is 'different', not 'deferent'.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is an [official Java-tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/examples/symbol/index3.html) on this. As mentioned by EJP you implement readResolve().

I rewrote the example-class for Java 1.6+: ;-)

import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

```java
public class RememberMe implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Contains all known instances by id. If you feel the need to permanently discard an object you have to remove it from this Map.
     */
    static final Map<Integer, RememberMe> knownInstances = new HashMap<Integer, RememberMe>();

    /**
     * There is always only one object by this id reachable
     */
    private final int    id;
    /**
     * A changeable field
     */
    private       String name;
    /**
     * Another changeable field
     */
    private       String location;

    /**
     * Private constructor so we can ship existing instances
     */
    private RememberMe(final int id, final String name, final String location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    /**
     * This is how you create and access objects of this class. name and location are ignored if an id already exists
     */
    public static RememberMe getRememberMe(int id, String name, String location) {
        synchronized (knownInstances) {
            final RememberMe oldValue = knownInstances.get(id);
            if(oldValue != null) {
                return oldValue;
            } else {
                final RememberMe newValue = new RememberMe(id, name, location);
                knownInstances.put(id, newValue);
                return newValue;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    /**
     * This function is called after the Object is fully created (i.e. after constructor was called and all objects
     * referenced by field have been created). Now we only need to decide if it is the first of it's kind or we already
     * know an object by that id.
     */
    private Object readReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
        synchronized (knownInstances) {
            final RememberMe oldValue = knownInstances.get(id);
            if(oldValue != null) {
                return oldValue;
            } else {
                knownInstances.put(id, this);
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## How this works?

- There is a map knowing all instances of the class
- If an object is deserialized we use `readReplace()` to replace it by any instance previously created with the same id.

You need to watch out, that during Object-creation the Object does not register itself anywhere as those references would not be changed by `readReplace()`; because of this the class is registered in `knownInstances` inside `getRememberMe` and not inside the constructor!

If you want to be able to let the GC recycle objects of this class you may want to replace `HashMap` or its values by some Weak*-variant.