# How to send child classes over Socket and recover them at the other end

Tags: java, sockets, inheritance, serialization

Suppose we have the following classes:

```
class Packet implements Serializable { ... };
class OpenConnectionPacket extends Packet { ... };
class DataPacket extends Packet { ... };
class CloseConnectionPacket extends Packet { ... };
```

Now, I want to be able to send an arbitrary packet like this:

```
Socket s = ...;
ObjectOutputStream toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

Packet p = ...;

toServer.writeObject(p);
```

and recieve it from the other end:

```
Socket s = ...;
ObjectInputStream fromClient = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

Packet p = (Packet) fromClient.readObject();
```

Is this possible? How? (If it is, I guess is should override the `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods, and maybe have something like a `int type;` or some enum in the parent class `Packet` in order to identify each child?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override `writeObject()` and `readObject()`.

It works by its default implementation until and unless you write your custom logic while serialization if needed.

For more info have a look at below links

- [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)
- [Serialization - readObject writeObject overides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963445/serialization-readobject-writeobject-overides)

Comment: It will work with the default implementation even if p is not a Packet but a child class?

Comment: yes there is no issue but opposite is not true. Try it yourself.