# Java deserialization how to ignore property

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a list of objects serialized into a file:

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

    public String location;
    public SomeClass lastUpdatedAt;

}
```

Unfortunately, I now have a new version of this class, and we don't have SomeClass anymore; The reason is complex but I need to serialize this back into this new form (this is an example class and not the actual class obviously):

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

    public String location;

}
```

In short, I'd like to ignore a property at deserialization.

**Please not that I cant change the original class source file. I only have the new source file**

However **ObjectInputStream** fails when it tries to find the **SomeClass** on the classpath:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream is;
    File f = getSavedFile();
    if (f.exists()) {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ArrayList<MyClass> result = (ArrayList<MyClass>) is.readObject(); //fails
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //ClassNotFound exception because SomeClass is not on the classpath.
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

I know you can extend **ObjectInputStream** and implement something there, but I'm not familiar with serialization that much and hope that someone solved the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

    public String location;
    public transient SomeClass lastUpdatedAt;

}
```

Maybe you have success with that. If doesn't work then you have to override the method.

For this reason I don't like the automated serialization and I do manually: implementing what field to serialize and how.

Every time you update your code you will have the same issue with backward compatibility if you use the build in function.

Comment: This'd work, but something important (I'll edit my question) I forgot: I cant change the original class source.

Answer (score 2):

making it transient will exclude it from serialization

```
public transient SomeClass lastUpdatedAt;
```

according to [jls-8.3.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3)

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part
>   of the persistent state of an object.

Comment: Same problem as above. I cant make any changes to the original source. Its a running service I need to update with a completely new one while also keeping legacy data serialized into files.... In short

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<MyClass> result = (ArrayList<MyClass>) is.readObject(); //fails
```

Actually this would fail, because the elements list signature doesn't match! Because MyClass has 1 or more field renamed, added, removed, type changed.

```
MyClass { int a; }

MyClass { String a; }
```

will break the deserialization.

What you could try is to override the `equals()` and the `hashCode()` methods in order to make your MyClassNew to looks like MyClass.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12963580/5505680) you can see more how to override now the desired method. That should give you a solution.

```
   private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        location = (String) stream.readObject();
    }
```

Comment: This gives me an error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: 0

Comment: Also, I have the same serialVersionUID in both classes, at least

Comment: @breakline that is also needed, forgot to mention, but Eclipse it generates usually