# Crash : Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: java, android

I follow flow ipay88 starting setup payment object

```
payment = new IPayIHPayment();
                        payment.setMerchantKey(marchantKey);
                        payment.setMerchantCode(marchantCode);
                        payment.setPaymentId(generateId("WoW"));
                        payment.setRefNo(generateRefNo());
                        payment.setAmount(amount);
                        payment.setProdDesc(generateDescription());
                        payment.setUserName(nameUser);
                        payment.setUserEmail(emailUser);
                        payment.setUserContact(phoneUser);
                        payment.setRemark(generateRemark());
                        payment.setBackendPostURL(backendUrl);

                        Intent checkoutIntent = IPayIH.getInstance().checkout(payment, ipay88pay.this, new ResultDelegate(), IPayIH.ENV_PRODUCTION);

                        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
```

and class ResultDelegate :

```
public class ResultDelegate implements IPayIHResultDelegate, Serializable {

    @Override
    public void onPaymentSucceeded(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, String s5, String s6, String s7, String s8) {
        showSuccessUpload();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentFailed(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, String s5, String s6, String s7, String s8) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pembayaran gagal. Sila cuba lagi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentCanceled(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, String s5, String s6, String s7, String s8) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pembayaran batal. Sila cuba lagi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequeryResult(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionError(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, String s5, String s6) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Masalah hubungan internet. Sila cuba lagi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and this is interface ipay88 try to serialize:

```
public interface IPayIHResultDelegate {
void onPaymentSucceeded(String var1, String var2, String var3, String var4, String var5, String var6, String var7, String var8, String var9);

void onPaymentFailed(String var1, String var2, String var3, String var4, String var5, String var6, String var7, String var8, String var9);

void onPaymentCanceled(String var1, String var2, String var3, String var4, String var5, String var6, String var7, String var8, String var9);

void onRequeryResult(String var1, String var2, String var3, String var4);

void onConnectionError(String var1, String var2, String var3, String var4, String var5, String var6, String var7);
```

}

at the end got this error:

`Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = {packageid}.ipay88pay$ResultDelegate Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:`

Further I do reach to implement parcel but none of them also working. Anyone has the same problem like me appreciate sharing. tq.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the problem; the object you are trying to serialize is not serializable, most likely because it contains a variable wich doesnt implement serializable, and you didnt override the wriiteobject and readobject methods.

You can take a look at [Serialization - readObject writeObject overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963445/serialization-readobject-writeobject-overrides) for more info on how to do this

Comment: hi thanks for repyl, neither have doc ipay88 tell about implement Serializable. So sample that u give not same thing in ipay88